# OnIonChange not updating textarea state

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ionic-framework, jsx

```html
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {
  IonModal,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonTitle,
  IonButtons,
  IonButton,
  IonContent,
  IonTextarea,
} from "@ionic/react";

const CommentModal = ({ isOpen, title, sendAction, closeAction, comment }) => {
  const [commentText, setCommentText]  = useState(
    comment ? comment.text : ""
  );

  function handleSendAction(item) {
    sendAction(item);
    setCommentText("");
  }

  const handleChange =event =>{
       console.log(event.target.value)
       const {value}= event.target; 
       setCommentText(value);
   }

  //  (e) => setCommentText(e.target.value)

  return (
    <IonModal isOpen={isOpen} onDidDismiss={closeAction}>
      <IonHeader translucent>
        <IonToolbar color="primary">
          <IonTitle>{title}</IonTitle>
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            <IonButton onClick={closeAction}>Close</IonButton>
          </IonButtons>
          <IonButtons slot="end">
            <IonButton onClick={() => handleSendAction(commentText)}>
              Send
            </IonButton>
          </IonButtons>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonTextarea
          row={25}
          cols={25}
          placeholder="Your comment"
          onIonChange={handleChange}
          value={commentText}  
        />
      </IonContent>
    </IonModal>
  );
};

export default CommentModal;
```

This is my code I want to let the user enter a comment in textarea but unfortunately when I restart my compiler I can but later on it does not update or console the entered text.
I have used react hook useState to update state it works fine for OnChange but causes problem in Ionic.
Is this some issue with Ionic? or my code has some bug.

When I remove value it works fine and updates it but I want to add update feature hence I need value={commentText}.

Answer (score 0):

instead of onIonChange use **onIonInput**